# QCoreApplication::applicationVersion não "reconhece" o RC_FILE quando uso Mingw

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

Eu criei um arquivo [*rc* (**Resource File**)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3sk7e6b.aspx) simples e adicionei ele ao projeto (`winvertest.pro`):

- `rcexample.rc`

  ```
  #include "winver.h"

  VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
      FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
      PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
      FILEFLAGS 0x0L
      FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
      FILEOS 0x00040004L
      FILETYPE 0x1L
      FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
  BEGIN
      BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          BLOCK "000004b0"
          BEGIN
              VALUE "CompanyName", "Foo Bar CompanyName"
              VALUE "FileDescription", "Foo bar FileDescription"
              VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.1"
              VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Foo bar LegalCopyright"
              VALUE "InternalName", "foobar"
              VALUE "OriginalFilename", "foobar.exe"
              VALUE "ProductName", "foobar product name"
              VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.1"
          END
      END
      BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          VALUE "Translation", 0x0, 1200
      END
  END
  ```
- `winvertest.pro`

  ```
  QT += core gui

  greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = winvertest
  TEMPLATE = app

  win32:RC_FILE = rcexample.rc # my rc file

  DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

  SOURCES += main.cpp
  ```
- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include <QDebug>
  #include <QApplication>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication a(argc, argv);

      qDebug() << "applicationVersion:" << a.applicationVersion();

      return a.exec();
  }
  ```

Usando *MSVC2015 32bit*, o `applicationVersion` retorna:

> applicationVersion: "1.0.0.1"

Mas quando uso *Mingw 5.3.0* retorna vazio:

> applicationVersion: ""

Isto seria um problema com o Mingw, com o Qt ou eu esqueci de adicionar algo ao `.pro`?